# How to debug Lua 5.4 on VScode?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, lua, apple-m1

Initially I've been using VScode with plugin [satoren.lrdb](https://github.com/satoren/LRDB) which worked relatively well, but when debugging it only supported lua 5.3 and when I've executed the same script from CLI it was powered by lua 5.4.

I couldn't find how to reconfigure the plugin. [Github](https://github.com/satoren/LRDB) repos of that plugin doesn't seem to be active anymore.

There are any other more up to date and more popular plugins?
I've tried to find but found only some [chinese plugins](https://github.com/actboy168/lua-debug) which I couldn't really decypher how to configure/use.

my spec: macOS, M1

Comment: When I search `Lua` in VSCode EXTENSION:MARKETPLACE, I see `Lua Debug` and `Lua Debugger`, have you tried those ?

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl+Shift+X` (Windows/Linux) or `Cmd+Shift+X` (macOS) to open the extensions marketplace.

In the search box, type `Lua` and install the appropriate extension.

Once installed, open the `settings.json` file.

Inside the file, add the following code:

```
{
  "lua.runtime.version": "Lua 5.4"
}
```

Save the file.

Now you should be able to use Lua debugging successfully.

Comment: Doesn't work with satoren.lrdb extension. How it supposed to work? 

is this setting consumed by VSCode itself or it should work with particular VSCode debugging extension?
If you @as-jayavel could please elaborate or provide the source where did you got that and how it supposed to work?